# C# - Datagridview cannot bind data from datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, indexoutofrangeexception

I have `datagridview` binding data from `datatable`. When I checked the number of columns of `datatable`, it returned 10. However, `datagridview` got an error when showing more than 8 columns. The error is `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection` .Below is my code and also an error I got. Please help me!

```
public void SearchPatient(string query)
    {
        MySqlConnection MysqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString);
        MySqlCommand MysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConnection);
        MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MyAdapter.SelectCommand = MysqlCmd;
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        rows = dTable.Rows.Count;
        MessageBox.Show(rows + "  " + dTable.Columns.Count); // It showed 15 and 10
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = fullname;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = birthday;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = gender;
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = address;
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = phonenumber;
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = cmnd;
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = note;
       dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "ID benh nhan"; // Error: Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

    }
```

This is my database:
[image]

And my query is: `SELECT * FROM patientdatabase ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,15`

Comment: Paste a screenshot of your Quick Watch for dTable.

Comment: Can you post your SQL script?

Comment: @henocsalinas below are my database data and my query

Comment: What is the count of dataGridView1.Columns after you set it's data source? Check the Data Grid View properties in Designer View and see if columns are defined?

Comment: @henocsalinas  dataGridView.Columns.Count() returns 8

Comment: @tinchip so, if return 8 you not have dataGridView1.Columns[8], because the  collection as base 0, for example 0=1, 1=2, 2=3, 3=4, 4=5, 5=6, 6=7, 7=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like columns are added in the designer and your DataGridView's AutoGenerateColumns is set to false.
As your columns count doesn't match your data source, therefore  you are getting this error.

To fix this, either

1. Add columns in the designer to match the Data source
2. or, set dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns to True

See reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks for your help. I just set `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true` and It works.